# HttpSendRequest returns failure / error code 2 when Work Offline enabled

Tags: http, wininet

I'm trying to use use WinInet to make HTTP requests and `HttpSendRequest()` sometimes returns a failure while other applications and browsers seem to have internet access.
When I check `GetLastError()` it returns 2. This isn't one of the [standard WinInet error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it could be the Win32 `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

This is failing with multiple pieces of code but here's one I could easily test with:

```
'Split up the URL into its component parts
URLInfo = SplitURL(URL)
AuthFlags = IIf(URLInfo.lpszUserName = "" And URLInfo.lpszPassword = "", INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH, 0)

'Create the connection to the server
SessionHandle = InternetConnect(InetHandle, URLInfo.lpszHostName, URLInfo.nPort, URLInfo.lpszUserName, URLInfo.lpszPassword, URLInfo.nScheme, AuthFlags, 0)
If SessionHandle = 0 Then
  Err.Raise HTTPErrorInitSession, , "Failed to initialise the HTTP session: " & Cstr(Err.LastDllError)
End If

'Create the request for the resource
RequestHandle = HttpOpenRequest(SessionHandle, IIf(PostData = "", "GET", "POST"), URLInfo.lpszUrlPath & URLInfo.lpszExtraInfo, "HTTP/1.1", vbNullString, vbNullString, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD Or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE Or AuthFlags, 0)
If RequestHandle = 0 Then
  Err.Raise HTTPErrorInitRequest, , "Failed to initialise the HTTP request: " & Cstr(Err.LastDllError)
End If

'Send the request
RequestSent = (HttpSendRequest(RequestHandle, SendHeaders, Len(SendHeaders), vbNullString, 0) = 1)
'Wait for the "success" message
If Not RequestSent Then
  Err.Raise HTTPErrorNoHost, , "Failed to connect to the HTTP server: " & Cstr(Err.LastDllError)
End If
```

I've tried running a packet capture and looking at network traffic when it fails and it doesn't even try to make the connection.

What's going on here and why does it seem to occur randomly?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @EricLaw What code? It's a problem that's been solved and I posted a question with answer for anyone else that comes across it (as is [explicitly encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). Anyone fancy explaining the close vote?

Comment: @EricLaw Note that this occurred with multiple code samples (all based on WinInet) and all of them failed on the `HttpSendRequest()` while "Work offline" was enabled. As soon as it was disabled, everything started working afterwards.

Comment: Your original question failed to mention that you had "Work Offline" enabled, and you didn't update the question with that. I didn't notice that you'd answered your own question (partly because you couldn't accept your own answer yet) to provide additional information. And yes, "What's wrong with my code?" should be accompanied with said code.

Comment: @EricLaw Because at the point I had the problem, I didn't know it was in "Work offline" mode. If someone already knows the answer, why put it in the question? I also didn't ask what was wrong with the code, I asked why a function would return a particular error. This returned error is largely independant of the code itself (multiple failing samples) and I didn't give any code in the question because I already found it was a system state that was causing it.

Comment: @EricLaw My apologies, I've just seen the documentation that says it returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` when it's not in the cache. I'll keep the question for reference and the sort a clueless developer (*guilty look*) would ask.

Comment: FWIW, the "Work offline" flag exposed by IE is getting deprecated and .NET *should* be updated to stop looking at this state.

Comment: Oh, .Net was working fine which is one of the things that threw me, as half the app (in a .Net DLL) worked fine yet the other half flatly refused to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpSendRequest()` will fail with an error code of 2 (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`) when [Windows/Internet Explorer is set to "Work offline" and the resource is not in the offline cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This doesn't seem to effect .Net based HTTP clients or other web browsers like FireFox or Chrome making it not immediatly obvious if Internet Explorer is not the primary or default browser.

You can go back "online" by opening up Internet Explorer, going to the file menu (pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> if it's not visible), and unticking "Work offline". After this, programmatic attempts to use WinInet will work correctly.

Note that Windows/Internet Explorer can get into this state accidentally if you set up dial up/VPN connections for testing or occasional use and its not set to "Never dial a connection"